# Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (651 > 512) with Hugging face sentiment classifier

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm trying to get the sentiments for comments with the help of hugging face sentiment analysis pretrained model. It's returning error like `Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (651 > 512)` with Hugging face sentiment classifier.

Below I'm attaching the code please look at it

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, pipeline
import transformers
import pandas as pd

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('/content/drive/MyDrive/Huggingface-Sentiment-Pipeline')
token = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('/content/drive/MyDrive/Huggingface-Sentiment-Pipeline')

classifier = pipeline(task='sentiment-analysis', model=model, tokenizer=token)

data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/DisneylandReviews.csv', encoding='latin-1')

data.head()
```

Output is

```
    Review
0   If you've ever been to Disneyland anywhere you...
1   Its been a while since d last time we visit HK...
2   Thanks God it wasn t too hot or too humid wh...
3   HK Disneyland is a great compact park. Unfortu...
4   the location is not in the city, took around 1...
```

Followed by

```
classifier("My name is mark")
```

Output is

```
[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9953688383102417}]
```

Followed by code

```
basic_sentiment = [i['label'] for i in value if 'label' in i]
basic_sentiment
```

Output is

```
['POSITIVE']
```

Appending the total rows to empty list

```
text = []

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    text.append(row['Review'])
```

I'm trying to get the sentiment for all the rows

```
sent = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    sentiment = classifier(data.iloc[i,0])
    sent.append(sentiment)
```

The error is :

```
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (651 > 512). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-4bb136563e7c> in <module>()
      2 
      3 for i in range(len(data)):
----> 4     sentiment = classifier(data.iloc[i,0])
      5     sent.append(sentiment)

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1914         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   1915         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 1916     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1917 
   1918 

IndexError: index out of range in self
```

Comment: if you just want to disable that warning then use this ```transformers.utils.logging.set_verbosity_error()```

Answer (score 19):

some of the sentences in your `Review` column of the data frame are too long. when these sentences are converted to tokens and sent inside the model they are exceeding the `512 seq_length` limit of the [model](https://huggingface.co/transformers/task_summary.html#sequence-classification), the embedding of the model used in the `sentiment-analysis` task was trained on `512` tokens embedding.

to fix this issue you can filter out the long sentences and keep only smaller ones (with token length < 512 )

or you can truncate the sentences with `truncating = True`

```
sentiment = classifier(data.iloc[i,0], truncation=True)
```

Comment: What if you don't want to truncate the input? What is the canonical procedure to split the input into 512 tokens input in a pipeline?

Answer (score 6):

If you're tokenizing separately from your classification step, this warning can be output during tokenization itself (as opposed to classification).

In my case, I am using a BERT model, so I have MAX_TOKENS=510 (leaving room for the sequence-start and sequence-end tokens).

```py
token = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("your model")
tokens = token.tokenize(
    text, max_length=MAX_TOKENS, truncation=True
)
```

Now, when you run your classifier, the tokens are guaranteed not to exceed the maximum length.

Comment: What if you don't want to truncate the input? What is the canonical procedure to split the input into 512 tokens input in a pipeline?

Comment: I don't feel qualified to answer canonically but my advice would be to use an RNN-type neural architecture that will allow you to segment your input into a sequence of smaller chunks (paragraphs or sentences) that is more likely to fit within the 510-token limit.

Answer (score 3):

For those interested in suppressing the warning altogether (it's a valid use case), try:

```
tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilroberta-base')
tokenizer.model_max_length = sys.maxsize
```