# Huggingface reformer for long document summarization

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I understand [reformer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70419516/1052117) is able to handle a large number of tokens.  However it does not appear to support the summarization task:

```
>>> from transformers import ReformerTokenizer, ReformerModel
>>> from transformers import pipeline
>>> summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="reformer")
404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://huggingface.co/reformer/resolve/main/config.json
...
```

How would you construct the pipeline "manually" to use reformer for summarization?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="google/reformer-enwik8")
```

via [here](https://huggingface.co/blog/reformer).

However, this produces...

```
/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sentencepiece.py", line 177, in LoadFromFile
    return _sentencepiece.SentencePieceProcessor_LoadFromFile(self, arg)
TypeError: not a string
```

Comment: I think this should either be a separate question, or, better yet, a github issue on the transformers repository, if it doesn't work with the most recent version.

Comment: Update: it seems that this specific model does not provide a tokenizer altogether, which is why you're seeing the error message. You could use an alternative model instead, which provides a tokenizer, such as [`google/reformer-crime-and-punishment`](https://huggingface.co/google/reformer-crime-and-punishment)